# How to add Resource in IOS project at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to include images into the ios application in runtime.

Comment: Can you clarify? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? (Do you just want to be able to download assets and keep them on the device? In that case, yes, you can store files within the application sandbox.)

Comment: Please look into this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557273/tutorial-or-guide-for-scripting-xcode-build-phases/8274376#8274376

Comment: I want to download all images from server when application loads initially and later i have to use those images inside the application

Answer (score 4):

No. The Xcode project does not itself exist at runtime, and the application bundle cannot be modified.

If you need to add data at runtime, you will need to save it outside the application bundle.