# How to list all files for one target in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a XC command I can use to list all files for one target?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any environment variables available to a build script.

The best way that I know of would be to open the `pbxproj` file inside your `xcodeproj` bundle and parse it. Luckily, it seems to be in a plain text format [compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452707/library-to-read-write-pbxproj-xcodeproj-files) with `plists`. You could invoke the `plutil` command to convert it to XML or json for another tool/command to consume if that is your goal. You can utilize a "Run Script" build phase if you need this list as part of your build. You can also instantiate an `NSDictionary` directly with that file if that is useful to you.

The `plist` is pretty simple. It consists of a `root` dictionary with some version strings and a giant `objects` dictionary. Each object has an `isa` type and the one you are interested in is the `PBXNativeTarget` type. Scan until you find the target with the correct value for the `name` key. Once you find your target look at its `buildPhases`; AFICT the first entry in `buildPhases` is the key for the corresponding `PBXSourcesBuildPhase` object. That build phase object has a `files` array which contains yet another set of IDs (one for each file compiled into the target) which point to a `PBXBuildFile` object, which has a `fileRef` string as a key to *another* object, this time to a `PBXFileReference`. This object *finally* has a `path` key which will be the path to the source file.

Wait... did I say "simple"?

Comment: From what I've checked yesterday, parsing seemed like a possibility from my point of view as well. Thanks for your answer!